# Adding razor page in .net Angular project with microsoft identity does not inherit authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-identity-platform

When adding a new razor page to locahost/error/404 I am not able to authenticate the user.The meny on the top does have Register and Login. But if I press "Login" and get sent to the https://localhost/Identity/Account/Login, I am authenticated. So this is only on custom razor pages that this is happening.

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.ErrorPages._404Model
@{
}
<h1>404 - THIS PAGE WAS NOT FOUND</h1>
@(User.IsInRole("Admin") ? ",AUTHENTICATED" : "NOT AUTHENTICATED")
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages.ErrorPages
{
    public class _404Model : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I tried asking ChatGPT. I have google a lot. And I have tried to add different parts and codes, eg:

```
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


        public IndexModel(DbContext context,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
```

I tried to verify if Program.cs does have any limitations regarding to authenticate only users on certain pages.

I added `@(User.IsInRole("Admin") ? ",AUTHENTICATED" : "NOT AUTHENTICATED")` on a /Identity/Account-page, there it worked. On my custom pages it did not work.

**The issue**

So the issue is that all of the .net core pages/views I create does not inherit the authorization. The user appear to be unauthorized (and in backend code the user is unauthorized for these pages) . But if I go back to any of the Microsoft Identity pages he is authorized or if I go to my angular page I am authorized, so this is only something happening on my custom pages in the pages folder.

EDIT:
So still looking for what could be wrong I found out that if I put my page inside the Areas/Identity/Manage-folder, the user is authenticated and I can verify it.
But putting the file in /Pages/... will not be able to verify that the user is authenticated. If anyone have any idea what setting is limiting this, please tell.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your issue. Could you please share what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @TinyWang . I have added The Issue to the question which specify the problem

Comment: Do you want to explain that, your app already integrate Microsoft identity, so that when you hit one of your page, it should redirect to sign in page if no users is authenticated now. But you found that you can hit all the pages without sign in, if you want to sign in, you need to click the login button in the menu manually?

Comment: No @TinyWang
I am able to login with Microsoft Identity, and the pages made there. It works as expected. My angular page also work as expected. But when I créate a custom page/view in the pages-folder this page is not able to verify if the user has signed in or not.  `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` will return null. But going back to all other pages than the custom mine, will show that the user is logged in. So this only happens on my custom view/page. So I want to "inherit" the information, and verify on my custom page that the user is logged in.

Comment: it's an Angular + asp.net core application, and the authentication worked well, in angular pages you can see the user is signed in. Now you are creating a custom cshtml page, you also want to view the current user information, but you found that you can only see the `Login` button in the menu, which should display user name instead since user already signed in, am I right? If so, maybe a minimal reproducible sample is required for troubleshooting...

Comment: @TinyWang, Correct. And I have created a minimal reproducible sample, see the cshtml and cs file in the question asked above. Cant be less code than that. But even so...I am not able to get the user id on my page. The problem is not that he is not in Adminrole, the problem is that he is not authenticated.

Comment: yes but I can't reproduce the issue in my side via the codes you shared in the question...

Comment: So your page are able to get the logged in information of the user?

Comment: no, I can't create a sample for test only with your code snippets. How you create your project and how you add the authentication mechanism?

Comment: I use the standard OOB angular. Net core project that is in Visual Studio.

Comment: @TinyWang : See last edit. I was able to see the user information, but only when I put the razor page in the spesific folder. Not sure what "setting" is doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found two similar post on stackoverflow who helped me out, and it was the following two:

[User.Claims is empty for every page outside of Areas/Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000249/user-claims-is-empty-for-every-page-outside-of-areas-identity)

[How do I set up authentication & authorisation for ASP .NET Core 3.0 with PageModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550789/how-do-i-set-up-authentication-authorisation-for-asp-net-core-3-0-with-pagemo)

So I ended up with changing my Program.cs and added spesific authorization in my handler, and that was it

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
}).AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

And:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]
```

And that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Add [Authorize] to the page model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages.ErrorPages
{   
   [Authorize]
   public class _404Model : PageModel
   {
      public void OnGet()
      {
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Even though I am logged in I get: Request URL: https://localhost:44408/admin/ Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized Remote Address: [::1]:44408 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin